# Is there a way to mark specific lines in BBEdit and then iterate through them?

Tags: bbedit

I often find myself jumping between several parts of a lengthy document, and I've found no streamlined way of handling this. I've previously used TextPad for PC, and it had a great feature called Bookmarks:

- Press a keystroke, and the current line is marked. The bookmark shows as an arrow in the gutter.
- The same key toggles the marker off again.
- Another keystroke sends the caret down to the next bookmark.
- Yet another keystroke sends the caret up to the previous bookmark.

Is there anything like this in BBEdit? I loved that feature of Textpad, but I haven't found another editor that has something similar. Currently I use the awkward substitute of typing three slashes /// at a place I want to jump back to, then using ***<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>*** to re-find them, but that's a lot of keystrokes to set/remove markers and to iterate through them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are after is BBEdit **Markers**.

This article is a good place to start: [macdrifter.com/2012/01/bbedit-markers.html](http://www.macdrifter.com/2012/01/bbedit-markers.html)